# PHP and jQuery mobile File Upload working for desktop but not on mobile

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile, file-upload

Here's the form processing code:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$score = $_POST['score'];
$screenshot = time();
$screenshot .= $_FILES['screenshot']['name']; // the name of the file to save
$target = GW_UPLOADPATH . $screenshot;
$screenshot_size = $_FILES['screenshot']['size'];
$screenshot_type = $_FILES['screenshot']['type'];
```

And here is the form in HTML (also including jQuery):

```
<div data-role="page" id="main">
  <div data-role="header" style="text-align: left;font-size: 20px;">
        <?php if($mobile) echo $title; ?>
  </div><!-- /header -->
  <div data-role="content">
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <div data-role="fieldcontainer" class="score">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo GW_MAXUPLOADSIZE; ?>" />
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php if (!empty($name)) echo $name; ?>" /><br />
    <label for="score">Score:</label>
    <input type="number" id="score" name="score" value="<?php if (!empty($score)) echo $score; ?>" /><br />
    <label for="screenshot">Screen shot:</label>
    <input type="file" id="screenshot" name="screenshot" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add" name="submit" />
    </div><!-- /fieldcontainer -->
  </form>
```

The upload processes fine if I submit on a desktop computer, but when I access the site on my Android Chrome browser, it fails. Using error reporting:

Notice: Undefined index: screenshot in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\gw\modtest.php on line 45 Notice: Undefined index: screenshot in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\gw\modtest.php on line 47 Notice: Undefined index: screenshot in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\gw\modtest.php on line 48 Notice: Undefined index: screenshot in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\gw\modtest.php on line 52

I searched for a similar question and found one but the only answer was an unhelpful "php is server side, not client side." Any help or explanation would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You may need to add `$screenshot .= $_FILES['screenshot']['tmp_name'];`

Comment: jQuery mobile sometimes modifies your original HTML. I'd take a look at the rendered source on a mobile device (couldn't tell you how to do it on an Android).

Comment: Okay I read about the solution in the book jQuery Mobile Up and Running. It had to be a non-ajax form, since jQuery automatically forces forms to ajax. For future reference to anyone reading, the code is:
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" data-ajax="false">
Thanks you guys for the hint, particularly the part about jQuery modifying the code which was somewhat right. It works correctly now :)